# My generated texture is flipped

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm learning OpenGL and I don't understand why my texture is flipped if I give 
as UVs the "matching" vec2 of the mesh's vertex (vec3).

Example:

```
vert -256 -256
uv   0    0

vert 256 256
uv   1    1
```

I've had to try a different order for the UVs to be able to get the correct result...

Can someone explain why is that so?
Thanks.

Screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0y1g.jpg

This are the snippets of code I use:

```
// Create texture
GLuint texDebugId;

// RGBA Texture:
// R G
// B A

unsigned char texDebugBuf[] = {
    255, 0, 0, 255,
    0, 255, 0, 255,
    0, 0, 255, 255,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
};
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glGenTextures(1, &texDebugId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texDebugId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texDebugBuf);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


//------------------------------


// Prepare VBOs
static const GLfloat verts[] = {
    -256.0f, -256.0f, 0.0f,
    256.0f, -256.0f, 0.0f,
    -256.0f, 256.0f, 0.0f,
    256.0f, 256.0f, 0.0f
};

/*
// FLIPPED (but why?)
static const GLfloat uvs[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
};
*/

// OK
static const GLfloat uvs[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
};

// Upload vertices
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// Upload UVs
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_tex_id);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uvs), uvs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


//------------------------------


// Render
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint) pd.vertex_a);
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint) pd.uv_a);

// Vertices
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    (GLuint) pd.vertex_a,  // attribute id
    3,                     // size
    GL_FLOAT,              // type
    GL_FALSE,              // normalized?
    0,                     // stride
    (void *)0              // array buffer offset
);

// UVs
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_tex_id);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    (GLuint) pd.uv_a,      // attribute id
    2,                     // size
    GL_FLOAT,              // type
    GL_FALSE,              // normalized?
    0,                     // stride
    (void *)0              // array buffer offset
);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray((GLuint) pd.uv_a);
glDisableVertexAttribArray((GLuint) pd.vertex_a);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Note:

```
proj matrix: 
proj = glm::ortho(-320, 320, -240, 240, -1.0f, 100.0f); // 640x480 with 0,0 at center

camera matrix:
cam_target = glm::vec3();
cam_up = glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
cam_pos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f);
camera = glm::lookAt(cam_pos, cam_target, cam_up);

MVP matrix:
glm::mat4 mvp = proj * camera;
```

Comment: i would guess it's because opengl uses coordinate system in which y increases in the up direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because OpenGL actually expect the pixels ordered from the bottom-left.

So, when you give `(0, 0)` then what you meant is not the upper-left but bottom-left instead. In your case, you want it to be blue, but it shows you red instead.

Take a look at [this](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/), scroll down to number 12.

> **12. OpenGL's Lower Left Origin**
>
> Given a sheet of paper, people write from the top of the page to the bottom. The origin for writing text is at the upper left-hand margin of the page (at least in European languages). However, if you were to ask any decent math student to plot a few points on an X-Y graph, the origin would certainly be at the lower left-hand corner of the graph. Most 2D rendering APIs mimic writers and use a 2D coordinate system where the origin is in the upper left-hand corner of the screen or window (at least by default). On the other hand, 3D rendering APIs adopt the mathematically minded convention and assume a **lower left-hand origin** for their 3D coordinate systems.
>
> **. . .**
>
> Another common pitfall related to 2D rendering APIs having an upper left-hand coordinate system is that 2D image file formats start the image at the top scan line, not the bottom scan line. OpenGL assumes images start at the **bottom scan line by default**.

Comment: Mmmh, I used pixels from bottom-left... In glm::ortho I specified that -1 is at left, and 1 is at right with 0 at center (to replicate this: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/assets/images/tuto-2-first-triangle/screenCoordinates.png)

Comment: @TesX That picture is to describe the *screen* coordinates, which would be true. But, in your case you're dealing with texture UVs which a little bit different where the coordinates only range from 0 to 1.

Comment: "OpenGL assumes images start at the bottom scan line by default." Ahhh, that's why... Ok thanks :)

Comment: I've flipped the texture in the fragment shader and it works :)

Comment: @TesX that's one way to do it :p glad it worked out for you